# Datepicker with warning message?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation, datepicker

Can a little warning message be applied to a datepicker that can be shown if the date selected falls between TODAY and a numeric value of days in the future ie +7 ?

I've tried to set a minDate and maxDate but that only disallows any selection of dates outside those parameters. Whilst this kind of worked it had a flaw.. a user can delete the text in the field and manually type in their own date.. which doesn't get validated.

Also, I still would like everydate to be selected.. but if it is within the period set, that's when I'd like the message to be shown.

Here's what I'm using:

```
<script>
     $(function() {
          $( "#delivery_date" ).datepicker({ minDate: "+5D", maxDate: "", dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
     });
 </script>

 <input type="text" id="delivery_date" name="delivery_date" required  />
```

Comment: Well you could try referring to official jquery ui datepicker link ,jqueryui.com/datepicker/‎. can you attach a onchange event to the datepicker text field and get the current date and compare it.

Comment: you can probably disable the range of days

Comment: I wouldn't know how to code that though, I'm a real novice to javascript stuff. So far, I've tried setting the min date, but i still want the dates within the period to be able to be selected, and just have the user warned that they fall within a grace period

Comment: @LeeCollings Can you please post the code you have used, so that we can find the exact solution

Comment: I can do that, but the reason I Didn't was because I've tried several different kinds (jquery, html5) and I don't know whats the best.. so was hoping to expect recommendations on that front...

Comment: @LeeCollings What you have asked to do is possible. Just use a date picker and set the value validated via jquery. use onblur() to get the value, then check with the specified range of values..

Comment: @LeeCollings your script needs only year validation, you cannot add any dates/months as your wish.. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Are you able to post a sample of code that does this?

Comment: @Ganesh I don't follow you.. there's no validation in the script I posted. There's a dateformat?

Comment: I dont want to just have year validation, sorry I think you misunderstood me. Also that link I've seen, and there doesn't seem to be any validation messages on any example I try. They all seem to be standard examples I've seen on jquery's website

Comment: This question was answered in another question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632090/simple-datepicker-validation

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = new Date();
var d=x.getDay()+1; //because javascript counts from 0 and not from 1, the day that you'll get will be -1 from the actual day.
var m=x.getMonth()+1; //same here
var y=x.getFullYear();
```

Then add vars that get your date picker info (if someone set the date to 9.9.2013):

```
var d1= 9;
var m1= 9;
var y1= 2013;
```

then, if you try to alert when a date is 5 days from now:

```
if(d1-d==5)
   alert("the specified date falls on a specific period");
```

I hope you got the hang of it, if something is unclear, just ask.

Comment: I'm not after a message to be shown just on one date, the date set would allow any date between today and that date be shown a message, if that makes sense?

Comment: If you want the alert to include an amount of days, just change the condition of the if (the part inside the brackets). Right now it only applies to when d1-d==5 (the day in the date picker is 5 more than the actual day). If you want it to be when, for exaple, the day in the date picker is 5-10 more than the actual day, just change "d1-d==5" to "d1-d>=5 && d1-d<=10".
The && makes the 'if' be executed only if the first part ("d1-d>=5") AND the second part ("d1-d<=10") are both true.

Comment: Would you be able to write all of your code above into my code I posted so I can see how it fits together?

Comment: Can you please give me your whole code on jsfiddle.net for that? There's a spot for javascript, another for html and another for css. Then save it and press share on the top, then copy here the link.

Comment: I've tried to put your code into mine, and have the following: 'code'<script>
     $(function() {
          $( "#delivery_date" ).datepicker({ onSelect: function() {
         var x = new Date();
   var d=x.getDay()+1; //because javascript counts from 0 and not from 1, the day that you'll get will be -1 from the actual day.
   var m=x.getMonth()+1; //same here
   var y=x.getFullYear();   
         myOnChangeFunction();
   if(d1-d==5)
   alert("the specified date falls on a specific period");
    } });
     });
 </script>'code' But it doesn't seem to validate anything?

Comment: I've put it all in the boxes, and the datepicker window isn't appearing in jsfiddle

Comment: it does if i remove all the vars you've posted though

Comment: Give me the fiddle without my code. I don't know jquery so it'll be a bit tough for me but I'll try to understand the issue.

Comment: Fiddle just shows a box. Is that all there is to it? There should be 3 inputs for day, month and year shouldn't there? How do people enter the date?

Comment: No, it uses a popup datepicker from jquery

Comment: Well I can't do it, but what I can tell you is that all you need to find out is how to to find out which date was picked by the picker. If you can get this information you just need to set the info to vars as I've done above and my code will work.

Comment: Your code breaks the popup datepicker though, so i';m not entire sure your code is meant to be used in this way

Comment: It doesn't break it, you entered it in the wrong place. It should be after the code, you entered it in the middle.

Comment: If I enter it AFTER the code then it wont be read or processed at all :S Could you create a new jsfiddle then?

Comment: Okay so far I've got http://jsfiddle.net/GfUZq/4/ but I just need help in how to add the if statement. I tried pasting it straight after but the alert just fired when the page loaded. However, I don't want an alert that requires action.. just a line of text on the page (preferably above the input field).

Comment: I don't know if you've deleted that comment.. 'Is that waht you need?' but that was the fiddle I created, but without your IF statement

Comment: I see, your fiddle is now http://jsfiddle.net/GfUZq/5/ but that doesn't seem to make any alert appear

Comment: That's why I deleted it, I don't understand why the alert doesn't appear.

Comment: So, is that a definitive end to it? Or is there something else you could do?

Comment: I've been trying but I can't do that. You can open a question and ask what's wrong with my code, I suppose someone who knows JQuery will help you in a second.

Comment: You've deleted your comment again.. Please stop doing that

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of options available for official jQuery UI date picker. have a look at sample configuration

```
$("#dateBox").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    autoSize: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    setDate: new Date(),
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function() {
        // here you can have a function that will get called when user selects a date   
        myOnChangeFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: I could have followed that, but I don't know how to write functions. I started off using all those options and reading through the jqueryui datepicker website.

Comment: Are you able to show me what kind of function would need to be written?