# Simple datepicker validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation, datepicker

Can someone help me write a function for showing a line of text (preferably by showing a css class) for a jquery datepicker after someone has clicked a date?

The notice has to appear IF the date picked falls between TODAY and 21 DAYS FROM TODAY.

It's the function I need help with, as I don't know how to write it.

```
<script>
     $(function() {
          $( "#delivery_date" ).datepicker({ 
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
          });
     });
 </script>

<input type="text" id="delivery_date" name="delivery_date" required  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to validate it using [date.js](https://code.google.com/p/datejs), it has a fluent API which makes it very easy to express your conditions.

Example code might be:

```
var enteredDate = $("#delivery_date").prop("value");
var parsed = Date.parse(enteredDate); 
var start = Date.today();
var end = Date.today().add(21).days(); 
if (!parsed.between(start, end)) {
    alert("Date is valid");
} else {
    alert("Date is not valid");
}
```

[Test plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wm7neLnRavntXeDvD0Sm)

Comment: That alert changes only after 7 days. Besides, I don't want a browser alert, just a line of text. ANd also something that works on a selectdate, withotu a submit button.

Comment: Ok, I thought you just wanted a function that validates the input, you can expand on that of course ;)

Comment: I don't know how to expand, so far everyone has assumed I know how to write functions which isn't helping me. A week i've been asking questions on this site now.. it's doing my head in :(

Comment: Can i easily change the alerts to change the display: parameter of a css id?

Comment: also fixed the plunkr, date.js was confused with the date format, should now work as expected.

Comment: So does that mean I have to use mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: @LeeCollings You can overwrite the alert with everything you want. For example if you use jQuery and want to add a class: `$("#idOfMyElement").addClass("myclass");`

Comment: Updated plunkr with divs that show up when valid/not valid and it updates when you change the date.

Comment: Also, this is an example with (to be honest) crappy code. You should just get some hints from it on how to solve your problem ;)

Comment: Hmm annoyingly when I put it into my joomla site, its like the script doesn't run.

Comment: Your solution worked the best for me :) A few edits and i've got the alert changed to a show/hide css id depending on date clicked. Thanks very much!

Comment: Oh, seems I didn't read your text properly, I thought the date was only valid within the date range

Comment: actually you don't need external libraries, check my answer and use `onSelect` in datepicker

Comment: Yeah you don't need them but it makes the code much more readable (which also means more maintainable)

Comment: @narrowtux unknown methods of unknown library doesn't make your code readable, you spend time to research it, you spend server resources to include it, you wast your `<head>` with additional code, instead of deep learning jQuery and jQueryUI

Comment: @vladkras, ok have fun with getElementById and weird javascript date-related wtfs then ;)

Comment: @narrowtux 1. if you take a closer look on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632090/simple-datepicker-validation/18633179#18633179) you'll see, that the only pure JS object I use is `Data` 2. If you're unfamiliar with JS itself it's not a good idea to use frameworks based on it

Answer (score 1):

U can use `onClose` in datepicker

```
$(function() {
  $( "#date" ).datepicker({ 
  dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
  onClose: function() {
        valid();
    }
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle - example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/724/)

Comment: That's not what I'm after, I want an CSS div to appear when any date is selected between TODAY and 21days from today. AFter that, I don't want anything to appear.

Comment: Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/726/ , line 8 you can style it as you wish

Comment: 1. your example is not working `day == today || day == today+22` is not showing **the period** it only compares day picked with current day and cur day+22, so at least you have to change it to `day>=today && day<=today+21` but 2. what if today is 31st? - you will compare it with 53rd day?

Answer (score 0):

just use `onSelect` property when you init datepicker

```
$( "#delivery_date" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    minDate : new Date(),
    onSelect: function(str) {

        var lastDate = new Date(),
            nums = str.split("/"),
            userDate = new Date(nums[2], nums[1]-1, nums[0]), // reverse date
            period = 21;

        lastDate.setDate(lastDate.getDate()+period);

        if (userDate<lastDate) {
            // notify
            alert("inside 21 days period");
        }
    }
});
```

try **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/9VgTD/)**