# date format on input of type text jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a number of inputs as dates. The type is of text for the input.

I need to force and validate the date format so how can i achieve this?

If I change the type to date it is fine but have issues with chrome where the native calendar control gets rendered.

Cheers

Comment: is it a good for you http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ ?

Comment: Its more on the validation?

Comment: this guys solve issues with validation of datapicker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632090/simple-datepicker-validation