# Why my script is not run when I write to redirect to same page when validation was catch?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, hibernate, jsp

I write code for meal order system. I have CheckOut's JSP to input information to check out to order completed. I use **DateTimePicker(javascript's library)** to select date time to delivery. first, I select with the future of now and I proceed to check out, It's work. *But when I select with the past of now and I proceed to check out, My hibernate validation was catch and redirect to same page. and I try to select the date time again, but my script is not work same first time that I select.* Here is my jsp

```
                <h1>Check out: Please fill in your delivery information!       </h1>

                <form:form commandName="CheckoutDTO" action="Checkout"
                    method="post" class="form-horizontal"
                    onload="window.location.href=window.location.href">
                    <!-- onsubmit="return validateForm();" -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                        <form:input type="text" path="name" cssClass="form-control"
                            id="exampleInputEmail1" value="${cookie.customerName.value}" />
                        <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Room No</label>
                        <form:input type="text" path="room_number"
                            cssClass="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1"
                            value="${cookie.roomNumber.value}" />
                        <form:errors path="room_number" cssClass="error" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleSelectLocation">Delivery Location</label>
                        <form:select cssClass="form-control" path="delivery_code">
                            <c:forEach items="${deliveryList}" var="item">
                                <option value="${item.delivery_code}">${item.delivery_name}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </form:select>
                        <form:errors path="delivery_code" cssClass="error" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="asap" id="asap" value="1"
                            onchange="chkAsapCheckChanged()" /> <label for="asap">As
                            soon as possible.</label>
                    </div>


                    <!-- DateTime Picker -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleSelectLocation">Delivery Date and
                            Time: </label>
                        <form:input type="text" path="delivery_time" id="dpDeliveryDate"
                            class="form-control" data-field="datetime"
                            data-format="dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss AA" readonly="true" />
                        <form:errors path="delivery_time" cssClass="error" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="dtBox"></div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <form:button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Proceed to Order </form:button>
                    </div>

                </form:form>
       //<!--  Date and time picker -->
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#dtBox").DateTimePicker({

           dateFormat : "MM-dd-yyyy",
           timeFormat : "HH:mm",
           dateTimeFormat : "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss AA"

         });
     });
   </script>
```

I cannot copy DateTImePicker because The code is more than 30000 line.

Comment: I can give you a suggestion, why do you even reach hibernate layer or data layer if the selection was made of a past date. You can validate it on the frontend itself. e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632090/simple-datepicker-validation/18632352#18632352  See the plunker link mentioned there as well. Simple comparision of todays date to the date which has been selected will do. If this idea goes ok with your design, that is! You will get plenty of examples of such validations

Comment: Here is link :  https://github.com/CuriousSolutions/DateTimePicker